# Is it possible to access the subcollection of the collection on Cloud Firestore triggers via the callback's snapshot parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Let's say, I need to send an email to all the members of the group when the group is complete:

```
export const sendEmailToNewMember = functions.firestore.document('group/{groupId}').onCreate(async (snapshot,context) => {
}
```

The collection `group` has subcollection `members`. I check if the member's count has incremented and matches the total number of members who can join a group. If the final member has joined, I need to send all the members an email saying the group is complete.

The data structure looks like the one shown below:

```
collection group {
  membersCount: 9999,
  totalMembers: 100000,
  ....

  users subcollection
}
```

I tried accessing the collection through ref like so:

```
const usersRef = snap.ref.collection('users)
```

But, the result was `undefined`. For now, I access it using

```
await firestore().collection('group').doc(groupId).collection('users')
```

Is it possible to access the subcollection without awaiting it and from the `snapshot` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`document()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore.documentbuilder) takes path to a document and not a field. So if you want to trigger this function when any of the fields in group document is updated then set the path to `.document('group/{groupId}')`.

Also `snapshot` in [onCreate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore.documentbuilder.html#oncreate) will then contain data of that group's document only (the document that triggered the function). You'll have to explicitly read the sub-collection.

It seems you want to send email to new member that joins a group. You can instead trigger the function when a new user is added in user's sub-collection as shown below:

```
// Here user's UID would be ID of sub-document
export const sendEmailToNewMember = functions.firestore.document('group/{groupId}/users/{userId}').onCreate(async (snapshot,context) => {
  const { groupId, userId } = context.params;
}
```

Comment: I have removed the user count field and mentioned it in the edit. What I am trying to do is send the emails to all the users after the group is complete. So, I need access to the subcollection to retrieve their emails. Can you please let me know what do you mean by explicitly reading the sub-collection? Do note that I can fetch the group and their users using the groupId and `admin.firestore().collection('group').doc(groupid).collection('members').get()`. But, I would like to know if it is possible to use the snapshot itself to retrieve the users without awaiting.

Comment: @shet_tayyy no, you'll have to explicitly query for those sub-documents. Or you can store on array of emails in group document itself if you just need to send emails.

Comment: Thanks. So basically, I have to query. I was trying to avoid the read requests. I was aware of saving the emails in the group collection itself but I was trying to avoid duplication. But, it seems, it's the only way forward.

Comment: the actual answer is in the comments where I wanted to know if sub-collection can be accessed directly from snapshot. I'll update the question accordingly. Maybe adding it to the answers might help others as I have searched stack overflow and no answer for such a question exists.

Comment: @shet_tayyy I have mentioned it already on line 4. _"Also snapshot in `onCreate()` will then contain data of that group's document only. You'll have to explicitly read the sub-collection."_ Updated to emphasize on that.